# Getting the element coordinates after moving shapes in javafx using relocate

Tags: java, javafx, shapes

Basically, I am trying to move a shape using javafx relocate method. (Shapes being random polyline drawn by the user and recangle). The relocate method does not update the x and y coordinates of the shape. The Oracle docs states that relocate "Sets the node's layoutX and layoutY translation properties in order to relocate this node to the x,y location in the parent. This method does not alter translateX or translateY, which if also set will be added to layoutX and layoutY, adjusting the final location by corresponding amounts."

My question is how can I get the new x and y coordinates from the information I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties in the obvious way:

```
double x = polyLine.getLayoutX();
double y = polyLine.getLayoutY();
```

The line will be rendered by translating all the points by those values; i.e. the x coordinates of the points in the parent's coordinate system will be the x coordinates you retrieve from `polyLine.getPoints()` plus the `layoutX` value, and similarly for y. (I'm assuming here there are no other transforms applied to the line...).

Depending on your application, it may be easier to move the line by changing its points list, instead of using `relocate(...)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew it would be something really obvious. I have to move the shapes according to the mouse position and then save the new position of the shape - hence relocate seemed like a good option.